# TCP Connexion between Xamarin.Android and SDL_Net

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, tcp, sdl-net

I'm trying to establish a TCP connexion between a C# Xamarin Android app and a C++ app on a Raspberry pi.

On the C# client side, I'm using the TcpClient client from System.Net.Sockets :

```
// C#
static public bool Connect(string IP, string port)
{
    bool _connected = false;
    try
    {
        client = new TcpClient();
        IPAddress _ip = IPAddress.Parse(IP);
        int _port = int.Parse(port);
        client.Connect(_ip, _port);
        _connected = true;
    }
    catch
    {
        _connected = false;
    }

    return _connected;
}
```

This is a pretty straight forward use of the TcpClient class as you can see.

On the server side, using SDL_Net (1.2), here is my socket init :

```
// C++
string mNet::Resolve()
{
    socketSet = SDLNet_AllocSocketSet(2);
    if(socketSet == NULL)
        return "Could not allocate socket set : " + string(SDLNet_GetError());

    if(SDLNet_ResolveHost(&serverIP, NULL, Prefs::NET_PORT) == -1)
        return "Could not resolve server host : " + string(SDLNet_GetError());

    serverSocket = SDLNet_TCP_Open(&serverIP);
    if(!serverSocket)
        return "Could not create server socket : " + string(SDLNet_GetError());

    SDLNet_TCP_AddSocket(socketSet, serverSocket);
    return "OK";
}
```

and here is a dummy listener for testing :

```
// C++
void mNet::Update()
{
    int serverSocketActivity = SDLNet_SocketReady(serverSocket);
    if (serverSocketActivity != 0)
    {
        if(!ClientConnected) // new connection
        {
            clientSocket = SDLNet_TCP_Accept(serverSocket);
            SDLNet_TCP_AddSocket(socketSet, clientSocket);
            ClientConnected = true;
            SendToClient("1");
            Logger::Log("Client connected !");
        }
        else // server busy
        {
            SendToClient("0", true);
            Logger::Log("Client refused !");
        }
    }
}
```

I get no error from the initialization, and when I run a **netstat -an | grep tcp** command on the raspberry, I can see the port i'm using (1234) opened.

But when I try to connect from the android emulator, it seems that nothing is happening server side (no socket activity).
IP & ports are matching.

I'm not really used to networking, so is there something I'm doing wrong here ?

Additional info :

Targeting Android 6

RaspberryPi is running UbunutuMate

Networking C# class : https://github.com/arqtiq/RemotePlayerPi/blob/master/App/Network.cs

Networking C++ class : https://github.com/arqtiq/RemotePlayerPi/blob/master/Server/src/mNet.cpp

Thanks !

Comment: What ip are you using in the emulator?

Comment: I'm using the server local ip, which is 192.168.1.24 in my case

Comment: What do you consider to be the server? Please come to the point!

Comment: The raspberry is obviously the server in this case. both client (android emulator) and server are connected to the same local network.

Comment: From the emulator you can mostly not reach devices in the same lan as the pc where the emulator is running on. Better use a real Android device. FYI: the emulator has its own network which is not connected to that of the computer where it is running on.

Comment: okay so I deployed the app on an android device connected to the same network, but the connection still doesn't trigger anything server side ..

Comment: If the client can not connect then you will have exceptions in the Android client. Did you look in the logcat? How does the client behave? If there is a catch then do you know which exception throw?

Comment: No exception on client, I surrounded the Connect() with a try {} block and it goes alright. I tried without server started, the app freeze on Connect().